# Calculating degrees of representations of sporadic groups

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to calculate a list of the degress of irreducible representations of the sporadic groups, i.e [A001379](https://oeis.org/A001379) for groups other than the monster. The GAP code to achieve that would be:

```
List(Irr(CharacterTable(group)))
```

Sadly, GAP doesn't work on my computer, so I have to use Mathematica. I've tried getting a character table like so:

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SporadicGroup", 1}, "CharacterTable"]
```

But no matter what number I choose, I get Missing[NotAvailable]. Is there any way to calculate these lists, even pulling from an external database or hard-coding certain things?